# Hostname provided via SNI and HTTP are different (AH02031 and AH02032 ) Error

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, php5

I am using Apache 2.2 webserver on ubuntu Aws instance. My website goes down with below errors on error log,

> [ssl:error] [pid 46283] AH02032: Hostname  provided via SNI and hostname  provided via HTTP are different
>
> [ssl:error] [pid 50376] AH02031: Hostname  provided via SNI, but no hostname provided in HTTP request

Many website shows it might be some attack, How can I solve this issue ?

> can we block such request by adding any rule on htaccess or vhost ?